# SQL foreign key constraint with additional column value check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this situation

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    IsWholesaler BIT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser]
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    UserId INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        Name NVARCHAR(255)
)
```

One Customer which has IsWholesaler column set to true can have multiple users.
I have WholesalerUser table for this purpose but the Foreign key `WholesalerUser.CustomerId` is attached to `Customer.Id` but how to check the column `IsWholesaler = 1` ?

Comment: Are you saying when you insert values to wholesaleuser from customers,you need to insert the values which has only iswholesaleuser =1

Comment: I want to be sure, when inserting CustomerId to WholesalerUser table, that Customer.IsWholesaler = 1. Also I need same check when someone will updating Customer.IsWholesaler value to 0 to block that update. Stored procedures can solve this problem but I wanted to know if there is possibility for check at schema level

Comment: Your question is confusing to me..what you want to acheive can be done by after insert triggers and constraints..Can you please explain with some data on what  are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key can be defined over several columns at once.

- Add a column `IsWholesaler` to the `WholesalerUser`.
- Add a check constraint to make sure that it is always `1`.
- Define foreign key over two columns `(CustomerId, IsWholesaler)`.
- To define such foreign key the `Customer` table should have either primary key as `(ID, IsWholesaler)`, or a separate unique index on `(ID, IsWholesaler)`.

**Table `Customer`**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsWholesaler] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

Unique index to support foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID_IsWholesaler] ON [dbo].[Customer] 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [IsWholesaler] ASC
)
```

**Table `WholesalerUser`**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsWholesaler] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_WholesalerUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

**Foreign key**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WholesalerUser_Customer] 
FOREIGN KEY([CustomerId], [IsWholesaler])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id], [IsWholesaler])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WholesalerUser_Customer]
GO
```

**Check constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_WholesalerUser] 
CHECK (([IsWholesaler]=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_WholesalerUser]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WholesalerUser] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_WholesalerUser_IsWholesaler] 
DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsWholesaler]
GO
```